# Problem launching parole after upgrading to vivd (clutter-critical error)

Tags: xubuntu, 15.04

After upgrading to the most recent version of xubuntu, I can no longer launch parole.  Launching it from the gui results in nothing visible.  Launching it from the command line yields the following:

parole:5092): Clutter-CRITICAL **: _clutter_id_pool_add: assertion 'id_pool != NULL' failed

(parole:5092): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to check features. Have you initialized Clutter?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I don't know if this is related, but I have also had problems playing certain media files.  Also, I suspect that this has something to do with my graphics card/ driver: amd radeon hd 6900 / flgrx-updates.

Weirdly enough I can get parole to start by launching it from the command line as root.  But trying to play anything results in parole crashing after reporting a gstreamer error.

Comment: Saddly deleting ~/.local had no effect for me.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to delete the ~/.local directory (e.g. rm -fr .local) and restart the app.  Then it works, I was getting the same exact error and this fixed it.  Something gets messed up in the directory probably as a results of using root auth (sudo) for some commands, etc...

Answer (score -1):

`(parole:5092): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to check features. Have you initialized Clutter? Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Solution for my:

delete folder `~/.cache` and restart the app.